# How to avoid drag and drop layers?

Tags: jquery, html, drag-and-drop

I'm using the following functions provided by w3schools to create a drag and drop. It's easier to understand if you see my code:

http://codepen.io/TutTut/pen/qIGkD

When you drop one term onto another, it goes inside it. How can I avoid this?

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, I just checked against the tag type and made sure it only went into divs:

```
    if(thetag == "TERM"){
    null;
  }
  else{
    ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
  }
```